# Calculating probability of broken machine using Bayes Theorem

Tags: probability

I am getting really confused with the probability problem below.
I found the answer to part $(a)$ is $0.0469$ using the Bayes Theorem, but I am not sure if this is right.

> An industrial machine produces mechanical parts with a predefined specification. The manufacturer claims that the machine is capable of producing correct parts in $99.5 \%$ of the cases. The QC department has a method that is capable to determine whether a part falls within the specifications with  an accuracy of $99\%$.
>
> $(a)$ The first part produced by the machine fails to meet the specifications. What is the probability that the machine is broken?
>
> $(b)$ The next three parts produced by the machine meet the specifications. What is the probability that the machine is broken?

Comment: Taken literally, these two problems can’t be solved. What does it mean for the machine producing these parts to be “broken.” You can certainly use Bayes’ theorem to determine the probability of the parts’ being defective given that they fail QC, but I don’t see any way given in the question to relate that the the machine’s being broken.

Comment: I woukd think that broken means that the machine produces incorrect parts. (Probability of 0.05).

Comment: I don’t read it that way: you’re given that in normal operation, 0.5% of the parts that it produces are defective.

Comment: I get your point but I dont see any other ways...and there got to be a solution for this...

Comment: @RMsc The probability from (b) should be very small, because it's very unlikely that the machine can be broken and produce 3 parts that pass inspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on the problem interpretation:  the machine is either broken or it is not.  If it is broken, all the parts it produces are defective, else they are all perfect.

Let's say $B$ is the event the machine is broken, and $F$ is the event that the first part fails the test.  Then for (a),
$$\begin{align}
P(B|F) &= \frac{P(B \cap F)}{P(F)} \\
&= \frac{P(F|B) \; P(B)}{P(F|B) \; P(B) + P(F|B^c) \; P(B^c)} \\
&= \frac{0.99 \times 0.005}{0.99 \times 0.005 + 0.01 \times 0.995} \\
&= 0.3322
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is the answer I found too. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Following this logic, how would you do the next question:
The next three parts produced by the machine meet the specs. What is the probability that the machine is broken?

Comment: @RMsc For (b), apply Bayes again, but instead of $F$ , you have $F_1 F_2^c F_3^c F_4^c$, where $F_i$ is the event  that machine $i$ fails.

Comment: I have tried to follow that logic but I get a non logical result (containing e^5 in it) I am probably doing something wrong but cant figure out what...